# Output name of Multi Device Hybrid App CTP3 android configuration is always CordovaApp.apk

Tags: cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I recently upgraded to `Multi Device Hybrid App CTP3` (from CTP2) surprisingly the output for android configuration is always `CordovaApp.apk`, I couldn't find anywhere to change the name of app. 
(It exists in every time generated `AndroidManifest.cordova.xml` file)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot set output apk file name in VS. Visual Studio calls Cordova CLI to build the package and it generates the apk with CordovaApp.apk, Visual Studio does not pass apk name.

Comment: But in CTP2 the name of output apk was the project name if you would have renamed the project name the output would renamed consequently. I think this is a bug in CTP3